# enum value not updating in mysql table?

Tags: php, mysql

im using this script to update to columns in my table.

the first column 'close_account' is an enum value '0' or '1' and these appear as radio boxes in my database.

the second column 'account_status' is an enum value 'Active' or 'Deactivated' and this appears as a drop down box list in my database.

i'm not sure if the fact that they are a drop down box or radio boxes matters in this case.

however my problem is i am trying to get both close_account and account_status to update by running the following mysql query, close_account needs to update to '1' and account_status should update to 'Deactivated'. at the moment for some reason only 'close_account' is updating but not account_status can someone please tell me why?

thanks.

```
<? ob_start(); ?>
<?php

require_once('includes/session.php');
require_once('includes/functions.php');
require('includes/_config/connection.php');

session_start();

    confirm_logged_in();

    if (isset ($_GET['to'])) {
    $user_to_id = $_GET['to'];


}


if (!isset($_GET['to']))
    exit('No user specified.');

$user_id = $_GET['to'];


$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ptb_users WHERE user_id ='".$_SESSION['user_id']."' ");

if($result) 
{ 
mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET close_account='1' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());

mysql_query("UPDATE ptb_users SET account_status='Deactivated' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']."") 
or die(mysql_error());

header("Location: dashboard.php");

}
?>
<? ob_flush(); ?>
```

Comment: You know you can update more than one column at once in an `UPDATE` statement? `"UPDATE ptb_users SET close_account='1', account_status='Deactivated' WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user_id']` - also, please inpect the value of `mysql_error()`, if a query fails to run correctly there's a pretty good chance this will tell you what went wrong - I see you are dying with this as the message, does it show you anything?

Comment: What happens if you dump the query text from the page and run it manually?

Comment: Also [**please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: numeric enumerated values are confusing. Can you test what happens when you `SET close_account='2'` for an account? Does it store `close_account='1'`?

Comment: First question here, please read what to do [when you get answers](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).

Comment: On a completely paradigmatic note, I'd recommend `tinyint` rather than `enum` for values that are basically boolean values.  It's easier to maintain and easier for others to wrap their head around (should they maintain it).  `ENUM` is really only useful for when you have values that can have more than 2 states.

Answer (score 3):

Using numeric values for enumerated data is always confusing. Especially when enumerated data is overlapping with enum index values.

In your case apparently `1` enum-data was interpreted as enum-index(numeric). Use strings for enum-data instead for better readability and usage.

Consider an example:

```
DROP TABLE enum_tb;

CREATE TABLE enum_tb (size ENUM('x-small', 'small', 'medium', 'large', 'x-large') NOT NULL);

INSERT INTO enum_tb
VALUES ('x-small'), (2), ('5');

SELECT * FROM enum_tb;
```

Output:

```
mysql> select * from enum_tb;
+---------+
| size    |
+---------+
| x-small |
| small   |
| x-large |
+---------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

surprising?

MySQL stores the actual enum values when index is passed. Enum indexes begin from `1` and in the above case index `2` is `small`. Also `'5'` was considered as index to `x-large`.

Answer (score 1):

The systematic way to approach problems like this is to first isolate the problem to PHP or to the database.  The easiest way to do that is to go straight to the database without using PHP. Use the MySQL command-line utility (`mysql`), or use a graphical tool like phpmyadmin.

Use one of those tools to connect to your test database. (Not your production database. Always practice safe tests.) Run this query from a SQL prompt.

```
UPDATE ptb_users 
SET close_account='1', 
    account_status = 'Deactivated'
WHERE user_id = somenumber
```

Replace `somenumber` with an actual, existing user id number.

Having said that, it's unusual for an enum to be a number. It doesn't make *much* sense to have an enum declared like this.

```
create table foo (
  user_id integer not null,
  bar enum('0', '1')
);
```

Something like this is much more common.

```
create table foo (
  user_id integer not null,
  bar enum('open', 'closed')
);
```

To update such an enum, use the string values.

```
update foo
set bar = 'closed'
where user_id = somenumber and bar = 'open';
```

Again, replace somenumber with an actual user id number.